# Writing into database only every 5 minutes?

Tags: c#, database, timer

I have tried using a timer to write data into the database every 5 minutes, but it doesn't work. Basically, data is streaming from my API every second but I only need my program to write one line of data every 5 minutes.

Here are my attempted codes:

```
                    /* print out the info from every person in te frame*/
                    // foreach ( Person person in people )
                    for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
                        System.Console.Write("Person id" + people.get(i).id + " , face x coordinate: " + people.get(i).face.x + "\n");
                        System.Console.Write("Person id" + people.get(i).id + " , face y coordinate: " + people.get(i).face.x + "\n");
                        System.Console.Write("Person id" + people.get(i).id + " , face width coordinate: " + people.get(i).face.width + "\n");
                        System.Console.Write("Person id" + people.get(i).id + " , face height coordinate: " + people.get(i).face.height + "\n");
                        System.Console.Write("Person id" + people.get(i).id + " , Emotion - Joy: " + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.joy_score + "\n");
                        System.Console.Write("Person id" + people.get(i).id + " , Emotion - Surprise: " + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.surprise_score + "\n");
                        System.Console.Write("Person id" + people.get(i).id + " , Emotion - Anger: " + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.anger_score + "\n");
                        System.Console.Write("Person id" + people.get(i).id + " , Emotion - Fear: " + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.fear_score + "\n");
                        System.Console.Write("Person id" + people.get(i).id + " , Emotion - Sadness: " + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.sadness_score + "\n");
                        System.Console.Write("Person id" + people.get(i).id + " , Emotion - Disgust: " + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.disgust_score + "\n");



                         //this is where I attempted to write data into database at only 5 minute intervals
                         var timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
                         timer.Interval = 300000;
                         timer.Elapsed += (_s, _e) =>{
                         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\sit\Desktop\(NEW) LEA WINFORMS\28June_LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonEffectivenessAnalysis\LessonAnalysis.mdf;Integrated Security=True")) {
                                conn.Open();

                                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_VIDEO(JOY_SCORE,SURPRISE_SCORE,ANGER_SCORE,FEAR_SCORE,SADNESS_SCORE,DISGUST_SCORE) VALUES('" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.joy_score.ToString() + "','" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.surprise_score.ToString() + "','" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.anger_score.ToString() + "','" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.fear_score.ToString() + "','" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.sadness_score.ToString() + "','" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.disgust_score.ToString() + "')", conn)) {

                                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader()) {

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }; timer.Enabled = true;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, is there an exception or is it just that there is never any entry in the database? As for your code, as it's an insert you should use `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()` rather than a reader as it's not selecting anything. Also, it's bad practice to build the sql string like this, you should use sql parameters for readability and avoiding any potential sql injection. Finally, your timer seems to be created inside the for loop for `people`, that would create a new timer on each iteration which is unlikely to be a good thing.

Comment: Looks like logic error. You have a temporary timer variable that gets instantiated each time in the loop destroying the previously instantiated object. When that loop is finished, all temporary variables in that loop gets destroyed. You need to move this logic outside of the loop. 

loop the data and put it in a queue or a list.  The timer sits outside of the loop that runs independently and every 5 minutes it reads the queue or list then remove that item on the list after written to db.

Comment: Also there is an uncaptured closure on `i`

Answer (score 0):

Try by putting timer in an array (before the loop) with the size of people.size(), and use i as its index.

Edits:
Something like this...

```
List<System.Timers.Timer> timers = new List<System.Timers.Timer>();
int interval = 0;      // set this to -300000 if you want the first one to be 0 seconds.
for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
    // Outputs.....

    interval += 300000;           // adds up 5 minutes each loop.
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
    timer.Interval = interval;
    timer.Elapsed += (_s, _e) =>{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=...")) {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO...", conn)) {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader()) {}
        }
    }
    timers.add(timer);
}; 

foreach (var t in timers) {
    t.Enabled = true;
}
```

This is just my logic, I have done something similar in Java.
**Note that this was not tested.**

Comment: What do you mean by this?